# Can you do addition/multiplication with Big O notations?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I'm currently taking an algorithm class, and we're covering Big O notations and such. Last time, we talked about how

```
O (n^2 + 3n + 5) = O(n^2)
```

And I was wondering, if the same rules apply to this:

```
O(n^2) + O(3n) + O(5) = O(n^2)
```

Also, do the following notations hold ?

```
O(n^2) + n
```

or

```
O(n^2) + Θ (3n+5)
```

The later n is outside of O, so I'm not sure what it should mean. And in the second notation, I'm adding O and Θ .

Comment: I prefer not to use this kind of notation without defining it, since it's not clear what it is supposed to mean. Probably, O(x) + O(y) is supposed to mean O(x+y), likewise O(x) + y; when you mix asymptotic classes like O(n^2) + Θ (3n+5), it becomes vaguer still. If you are given an exercise involving this kind of stuff, ask for clarification.

Comment: Mathematically, O(n^2) + Θ (3n+5) is very well defined and there is no reason to doubt its meaning. But in an algorithm class that might have badly defined O( ) in the first place, it might not be obvious, and confusing for the students.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At least for practical purposes, [the Landau `O(...)` can be viewed as a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) (hence the appeal of its notation).  [This function has properties for standard operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Properties), for example:

```
O(f(x)) + O(g(x)) = O(f(x) + g(x))
O(f(x)) * O(g(x)) = O(f(x) * g(x))
O(k*f(x)) = O(f(x))
```

for well defined functions `f(x)` and `g(x)`, and some constant `k`.

Thus, for your examples,

Yes:  `O(n^2) + O(3n) + O(5) = O(n^2)`
and:
`O(n^2) + n = O(n^2) + O(n) = O(n^2)`,
`O(n^2) + Θ(3n+5) = O(n^2) + O(3n+5) = O(n^2)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! But I don't fully understand why Θ (3n+5) can simply be turned into O(3n+5) ? If I'm correct, Θ(3n+5) should mean 'grows exactly like 3n+5', and so I could say that it also 'grows no faster than 3n+5', thus making Θ (3n+5) = O(3n+5) ?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly right.  `O(3n+5)` is a slightly more general, less specific statement --- you **can't** make the reverse statement that `O(3n+5) = Θ(3n+5)`, because technically `n^0.5 = O(n^2)` (because `n^2` is still an upper bound), but `n^0.5 ≠ Θ(n^2)`

Comment: Hello @DilithiumMatrix can you tell me a link of a university/book where I can find the rule which allows the step O(n^2) + O(3n+5) = O(n^2) please?

Comment: *"for well defined functions f(x) and g(x), and some constant k."* The constant k needs to be nonzero.

Answer (score 2):

The notation:

```
O(n^2) + O(3n) + O(5) = O(n^2)
```

as well as, for example:

```
f(n,m) = n^2 + m^3 + O(n+m)
```

is abusing the equality symbol, as it violates the axiom of equality. To be more formally correct, you would need to define O(g(x)) as a set-valued function, the value of which is all functions that do not grow faster than g(x), and use set membership notation to indicate that a specific function is a member of the set.

Addition and multiplication is not defined for Landau's symbol (Big O).

Comment: How do those examples violate (which?) axiom of equality?

Comment: The symmetric axiom: "if a = b, then b = a". Most uses of Landau's symbol are of the form: f(x) = O(g(x)), meaning that "there exist constants N and C such that |f(x)| <= C * |g(x)| for all x > N", and not denoting equality. (contrary to usage which specifically says "f(x) is O(g(x))", or similar)

Comment: `O(n^2) + O(3n) + O(5) = O(n^2)` does not abuse the equality symbol. The equal sign here notes equality of sets.

Answer (score 0):

Also the following notations hold

```
O(n^2) + n = O(n^2)
```

and

```
O(n^2) + Θ(3n+5) = O(n^2), Θ(n)
```

Hope it makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

In complexity theory, the Landau symbols are used for sets of functions. Therefore `O(*)` does not represent a single function but an entire set. The `+` operator is not defined for sets, however, the following is commonly used when analyzing functions:

```
O(*) + g(n)
```

This usually represents a set of functions where `g(n)` is added to every function in `O(*)`. The resulting set can be represented in big-O notation again.

```
O(*) + O(**)
```

This is similar. However, it behaves like a kind of cartesian product. Every function from `O(**)` is added to every function from `O(*)`.

```
O(*) + Θ(*)
```

The same rules apply here. However, the result can usually not be expressed as `Θ(**)` because of the loosening by `O(*)`. Expressing it as `O(**)` is still possible.