# Big Oh-Notation Q

Tags: java, big-o

I've got a big O notation of O(n^2 + n + n), just want to make sure, this is just O(n^2) correct? Basically I just a for-loop that goes through all of n with another for-loop that does the same inside the first one, then two separate for-loops that also go through all of n.

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: O(n^2) is correct.You can follow this answer as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168800/can-you-do-addition-multiplication-with-big-o-notations

Comment: The highest order is the only one which matters for large values of `n`

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in Big-O notation we only consider the fastest growing term of N.
Although if we are comparing two very similar performing algorithms even other terms may matter.
For eg:
If an algorithm has N operation and other has 2N operations although both of them are O(N) but still the later will perform poorer than the former.

Hence in your case your algorithm's Big O notation is O(N^2).

Comment: fastest growing might not be correct for small values of N. O(n^2 + 1e9 * n) I would say; biggest value for large enough values of N.