# Basic time complexity question. Time complexity of this simple function

Tags: python, time-complexity

I'm farily new to time complexity. I'm looking for the time complexity of this code

```
def func(arg):
  list= []
  for i in range(len(arg):       
      list.append(arg.count(i)     
  return list
```

I know that the loop would make it O(n), but then count is also O(n) in python, would that make this function O(n) or O(n<sup>2</sup>)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a loop within a loop:

```
for i in range(len(arg)): # outer loop => O(n)
      arg.count(i)  # inner loop hidden inside a function => O(n)
```

So that's `O(n^2)`.

If you wanted two loops that sum to `O(n)`, you'd need something like this:

```
for x in range(N): # O(N)
    ... # do stuff

for y in range(N): # O(N)
    ... # do other stuff
```

The overall complexity will be [the sum of the loops' complexities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168800/can-you-do-addition-multiplication-with-big-o-notations), so

```
O(N) + O(N) = O(2 * N) ~= O(N)
```

Answer (score 0):

O(n^2).
The outer loop executes n times the inner statement(which is O(n)) so we get quadratic complexity.